# How to pass data from ViewModel to another ViewModel

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have two viewmodels, one contains the necessary data for the user, a classic api fetch, and the second viewmodel is also an api fetch, but I want to insert the data from the first into the second, whenever I try, it always outputs nil, although before that I ensure that it cannot output it because I know it exists because the fetch function was called first.

```
class UserPostViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: UserResponse?
    
    @Published var phoneNumber:String = ""
    @Published var firstName:String = ""
    @Published var lastName:String = ""
    @Published var selectedImage: UIImage?

    
    @Published var normalizedMobileNumberField:String = ""
    
    
    func createUser() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "privateapi") else {
            return
        }
        

        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else{
                return
            }
            do {
                let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserResponse.self, from: data)
                if self.normalizedMobileNumberField != "The number you enter is invalid." {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.user = response
                        if let userData = self.user {
                            print(userData.data.id)
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                } else {
                    print("You can't register application")
                }
                
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    

}
```

This is the second one:

```
class GetTokenViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var tokenData: DataToken?
    var userVM = UserPostViewModel()
    func fetchData() {
        let urlString = "privateapi/\(userVM.user.token)"
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
            var request = URLRequest(url:url)
            

            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseToken.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        self.tokenData = decodedData.data
      
                        print("TOKEN: \(self.tokenData?.token)")
                    }
                    
                } catch {

                    print("Error decoding JSON in gettoken: \(error)")
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

How to pass data from First ViewModel to the second?

I know that these codes have some error but I deleted every private information, but I believe that there is minimal code for understanding my question.

Comment: View models should never talk to each other or know about each other. Move any shared information down to a manager.

Comment: @loremipsum Could you expand a bit on what you mean by a manager in this situation. I'm still trying to get my head around how to architect SwiftUI apps for various situations.

Comment: If your goal is how to architect SwiftUI apps you should forget about view models. They are only appropriate in very few circumstances. Managers are a common term there are many tutorials on MVVM and MVC that will elaborate. I like dependency injection and making my own property wrappers. This question is asked all the time on SO too, if you search around you will find many approaches.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, the `View` struct is equivalent to a view model but it is an immutable value type instead of an object that helps prevent consistency bugs. The property wrappers help it behave like an object. You pass data down the View struct hierarchy either with `let` if you want read access or `@Binding var` if you want write access. SwiftUI will track that these lets/vars are read in `body` and then `body` will be called whenever changes are detected. Transform the data as you pass it along from complex model types to simple value types.

`@State` declares a source of truth and `@StateObject` is when you need a reference type in an `@State` because you are doing something asynchronous or need to work around the limitations of closures in structs. Because these states are sources of truth you can't pass anything in because they won't be able to detect changes the same way the View struct can with `let` or `@Binding var`.

The best way to call web API in SwiftUI now is `.task` and `.task(id:)`. The task will start when the view appears, cancelled if it disappears, or restarted if the `id` changes. This can completely remove the need for an object.